# How to create soap wsdl request template using php

Tags: php, xml

this my xml request which i want to create for service.

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <aut:AuthenticationHeader>
     <aut:LoginName>John</aut:LoginName>
     <aut:Password>Johnpass</aut:Password>
     <aut:Culture>en_US</aut:Culture>
     <aut:Version>8</aut:Version>
  </aut:AuthenticationHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <hot:GetCancellationPolicies>
     <hot:hotelId>19752</hot:hotelId>
     <hot:hotelRoomTypeId>20955</hot:hotelRoomTypeId>
     <hot:dtCheckIn>2017-06-25</hot:dtCheckIn>
     <hot:dtCheckOut>2017-06-28</hot:dtCheckOut>
  </hot:GetCancellationPolicies>
```

and that is my php code

```
$p = new stdClass;
$p->request->HotelId                     = '19752';
$p->request->HotelRoomTypeId             = '20955';
$p->request->dtCheckIn                   = '2017-06-25';
$p->request->dtCheckOut                  = '2017-06-28';
$quote = $client->GetCancellationPolicies($p);
```

actually i am getting error.which is mentioned below.
Error Details:
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'nResId' property

i'm new in web services it would be great if someone could help me out of it.

Answer (score -1):

from the wsdl, you should generate the corresponding PHP sdk using a WSDL to php generator such as the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project as you won't wonder how to construct the request, in addition, it'll ease you handling the response as everything is OOP